# can't echo the array: only able to print it: and only echo the specific array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

```
<?php 
foreach ($recorded as $rows ) 
    {
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r ($rows); 
        echo "</pre>";

        echo "<img src='".base_url()."upload/thumbs/".$rows->file_name."'/>";
    } 
?>
```

When I print the `$rows` the results are:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [file_name] => steve-big.jpg
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [file_name] => steve1-big.jpg
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [file_name] => steve2-big.jpg
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [file_name] => steve3-big.jpg
        )

)

Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [file_name] => size-5-5-width-m.jpg
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [file_name] => 3316783.jpg
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [file_name] => 3316786.jpg
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [file_name] => 3316792.jpg
        )

)
```

But why can't I echo it?

I am using codeIgniter, and this is the error message I get:

> A PHP Error was encountered | Severity: Notice | Message: Trying to get property of non-object | Filename: views/mothershop.php | Line Number: 17

But I am only able to echo it if i give it a specific number like this: `$rows[0]->file_name`, `$rows[1]`, and so on.

Please, help, this really makes me confuse.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question is how to echo all the file_name correctly.

Comment: Why don't you just do this: `foreach ($recorded as $rows) 
  array_walk($rows, function($v){
   echo "<img src='" . base_url() . "upload/thumbs/" . $v->file_name . "'/>";
  });` ?

Comment: @klaudia your question lies the answer.Just replace $rows[0]->file_name to $rows[0]->file_name

Comment: @Rizier123 ^thats what i want.

Comment: @klaudia Should I convert it to a answer?

Comment: I think, yes you should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
foreach ($recorded as $rows) 
    array_walk($rows, function($v){
        echo "<img src='" . base_url() . "upload/thumbs/" . $v->file_name . "'/>";
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

As we can see `$rows` contains again array. So you cant not `echo` it. Instead you have to use `print_r`, to`echo` you have to iterate `$row` array. Try below code.

```
<?php 
foreach ($recorded as $rows ) 
    {
        // echo "<pre>";
        // print_r ($rows); 
        // echo "</pre>";
        foreach ($rows as $r) 
        {
            echo "<img src='".base_url()."upload/thumbs/".$r->file_name."'/>";
        } 
     }
?>
```

this may help you.

Comment: That works! :)  But it doesn't clean as I have to have double foreach there. IS there the cleanest way to achieve this?

Comment: look, you have one array where at 0th index there is again array and 1st index there is again an array....so it's need to iterate array.

Comment: @klaudia At the end there always be loops, but you could use array_walk or something like this

Comment: let me improve my answer

Comment: Your updated answer doesn't work. I have tried that many times.

Comment: that's because array in array. please follow my answer I again rollback it.

Comment: there are two arrays in your $rows. Which one you want to use ? index 0 or index 1 ?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
<?php 
foreach ($recorded as $rows=>$val ) 
    {
       echo $val['file_name'].'<br/>';
    } 
?>
```

Comment: Hi thanks. But I have tried this but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Check the error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered | Severity: Notice | Message: Trying to get property of non-object | Filename: views/mothershop.php | Line Number: 17
```

Because `$rows` is an array and does not have property called `file_name`.

Comment: But I am able to echo it like this `$rows[0]->file_name`

Answer (score 0):

try This code

```
<?php 
foreach ($recorded as $rows ) 
    {
        echo "<img src='".base_url()."upload/thumbs".$rows['file_name']."'/>";
    } 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to reiterate again on the rows
since the array structure of the result is 2 dimensional array

```
foreach ($recorded as $rows ) {

    foreach ($rows as $key => $value) {
        echo "<img src='".base_url()."upload/thumbs/".$value->file_name."'/>";  
    }

}
```

Comment: Is there a way so that I dont need to have double foreach there?

Comment: @klaudia: you can try http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php
or http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$baseUrl = base_url();
foreach ($recorded as &$rows) {
    foreach ($rows as &$row) {
        echo '<img src="'.$baseUrl.'upload/thumbs/'.$row->file_name.'"/>';
    } 
}
```